# jQuery external function needs some PHP values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my external JavaScript file, I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#follow').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/follow.php',
            data: {follower : session_id,
                   user : p_id,
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'followed'){
                    $('#follow').attr('id','unfollow').text('-Unfollow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On my normal page, I have this:

```
var session_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>',
    p_id = '<?php echo $p_id; ?>';
```

but this is not passing the variables into the jQuery function. I have these two variables being set before the JavaScript file is being called, also.

**EDIT:** I have tested this with the function on the same page as where the button is, and I passed in the PHP values with an echo, and it worked then.

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough code. Show the part where those two variables are declared.

Comment: Have you started sessions at the top of the page session_start();

Comment: Yes. When I use Google Chrome's developer tools, I can see that the variables are set to their appropriate numbers

Comment: Not related: Maybe you have certain reasons, but there shouldnt be any point to pass in an id and session through the POST itself, just retrieve these variables on the requested `follow.php` instead, this way you're always using the server to do 'server stuff'...

Comment: That could work with the session ID, but the $p_id is specific to that person's profile page, and I don't know how I would send it. Maybe an hidden input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a namespace in the jquery object allowing access to it even inside events. Like so:

```
$.mynamespace = { 
    session_id: '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>',
    p_id: '<?php echo $p_id; ?>'
};
```

Then reference those namespace vars in your code like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#follow').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'functions/follow.php',
            data: {follower : $.mynamespace.session_id,
                   user : $.mynamespace.p_id,
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'followed'){
                    $('#follow').attr('id','unfollow').text('-Unfollow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This will also make them available for any other jQuery events/callbacks etc

(NB: Make sure your variables are being set before you try to use them, i.e. higher in the script)

Comment: So I have this on the page:
`<script type="text/javascript">
  $.upnamespace = {
   session_id: '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>',
   p_id: '<?php echo $p_id; ?>'
  };
 </script>
 <script src="/custom_js/user_profile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
And then I put this in the external file:
`follower : $.upnamespace.session_id,
       user : $.upnamespace.p_id`
And it's still not working :(

Comment: I fixed it. You are forgetting your end curly bracket for the data :)